# Code Coverage Results: Export to Excel

Tags: c++, visual-studio, code-coverage, export-to-excel

There is a 'Code Coverage Results' window in Visual Studio which allows you to view the contents of a *.coverage file (generated by one of the VS performance tools).  I was wondering if there was a way to export the Code Coverage Results to excel for further analysis.  The tools in the Code Coverage Results window seem somewhat limited and was wondering if I was missing something.

I've queried quite a few statements and cannot find the answer I was hoping to find.  There were three main questions which did not seem to have answers:

1. Can you search the data within the code coverage results?  The typical VS search will not allow you to search within the Code Coverage Results window
2. Can the Code Coverage Results be exported to excel, or as a *.csv file?  If not, then can the *.coveragexml file (which seems to be the only export option) be imported into excel in a way that i would get a table similar to the one in the Code Coverage Results window?
3. Is there an 'Expand All'/'Collapse All' button for the Code Coverage Results window?  It would be nice to be able to expand all of the Code Coverage Result tree if possible ... or at least be able to expand a group of branches which have been expanded.

Any suggestions/input would be useful.

Comment: It does not look like there is an expand-all/collapse-all function in the 'Code Coverage Results'.  Not sure why VS seems to be so lacking when it comes to the code coverage results window.  A few thousand clicks later (in order to expand all branches of the code coverage results) along with a 'select all' and then a 'copy + paste' ... finally got the results into excel for analysis.  Not great processes.  Still wondering if I am missing something.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is this:

1. Export to XML (I renamed it to ...coverage.xml so it is recognized as an XML file but not sure if that's necessary)
2. Load with Visual Studio
3. Format in VS (Ctrl+K, Ctrl+D)

Now you can open this in Notepad++ for example (or any other good XML viewer). There you choose to close or open all text blocks.

Comment: Now that I think about it, there may be a plugin for Notepad++ that makes this workflow a bit easier. Have to check tomorrow.

Comment: thanks for the tip TobiMcNamobi.  I'll try it out and report back on how it goes.